# How to make something that looks like a SwiftUI Button being remotely tapped

Tags: swiftui

I'm curious, does anyone know how to make a view that looks like a native SwiftUI button, and use code to set some sort of state to make it look like it is being tapped or not? I know I could reproduce it using my own custom views, but I would rather there was a way to leverage as much of the standard SwiftUI infrastructure as possible, to avoid headaches with platform differences, etc. I don't want to have to deal with dark/light mode, or to hard-code any colours/shapes into my implementation.

For my application, I would always be using `.buttonStyle(.bordered)`, so chances are, the depressed state of the button is easy to spot. So here's some sample code to show what I mean:

```
struct RemoteTap: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // The "Control" Button
            Button ("Tap Me") {
                // What is needed to make the "Display" button look tapped and released?
            }
            .buttonStyle(.bordered)

            // The "Display" Button            
            Button ("Display") {}.buttonStyle(.bordered)
        }
    }
}
```

In the above example, I'm using an actual `Button` in the "Display" Button, but that need not be the case in the solution. In my application, I just need something that *looks* like a native button. It will never be tapped by the user and is just for display.

If it helps, I can see that there's a [`ButtonStyleConfiguration`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/buttonstyleconfiguration) struct in SwiftUI that has a `.isPressed` member. I just don't know what to do with such a struct once I've populated it according to what I'd like.

Comment: I'm curious as to what the use case for something like this is... Why would you want something that looks like a button but never intended to be tapped?

Comment: I’m trying to implement something like pull-to-refresh. When you pull a bit, a “button” is revealed. If you pull more, it is “tapped”. You never interact with it directly.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this ad hoc approach, adjust the colors as needed.

```
struct RemoteTap: View {
    @State var blink = false  // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 44) {
            // The "Control" Button
            Button ("Tap Me") {
                blink.toggle()
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+0.1) { // <-- here
                    blink.toggle()
                }
            }
            // The "Display" Button
            Button ("Display") {
                
            }
            .buttonStyle(.bordered)
            .foregroundColor(blink ? Color.white : Color.blue)  // <-- here
            // .background(blink ? .....)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a decent attempt! Where it could be better is in not overriding any colours or shapes in the native implementation. The call to foregroundColor has the problem of hard-coding in values for colours that may end up being incorrect, and that require complex logic to handle dark/light mode. Also the background call overrides the default look. So I hope for a fuller solution. Thanks for this, though. It will do, in a pinch. I have updated the question to steer solutions in this direction, and added a comment about ButtonStyleConfiguration.